# How to get AWS access credentials with login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-iam

My requirement is to access some AWS APIs from a mobile application(Written in flutter). Currently how I have done it is by creating an IAM user with only the permissions required and using the access credentials of that user I sign my APIs.

What I am looking to do is instead of storing these credentials with in my app. Is there a way to use some sort of sign in mechanism to obtain some credentials and use those for signing my APIs?

**Update 1:**

To add more context. This is purely a hobby project and mostly for personal use. And for my use case storing credentials with in application is more than enough. Anyway I have intention to publish it as an open source project and I want to add a better way to handle this. Currently am not storing any credential in my code but am adding it as a an ENV during build process.

I think I would be able to handle this if I create my own backend to generate temporary credentials. But if there is some other standard solution out there I would like to utilize that.

Answer (score 1):

Storing credentials in an application is an antipattern, and AWS provides features that prevent the need for you to do so.

Two alternatives off the top of my head.

The most obvious of these is [AWS IAM Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).  These permit you to bind IAM permissions to an EC2.  Any application or service on this ec2 is then permitted to perform the actions permitted by the IAM profile bound to the Instance Profile.

If you are running your application in EKS, you can leverage [IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) to bind IAM permissions to a service-account in the EKS cluster.

I assume you're running your service on EC2, and that therefore the InstanceProfile approach is easiest.

Comment: sorry. My question was not clear. I have changed it. Actually I am trying to call API directly from a flutter mobile application. I do agree storing credentials is anti pattern. Hence looking for an alternative solution